# Magento2 : How to add multiple product in cart using single form submission?

Tags: magento2

I am new in magento2 and using version 2.1.
I have to add multiple product in cart, the product can be any type and I want to add ajax validation as well with this functionality.

Can any one has idea to achieve this?

Thanks,
Chandan

Comment: Finally I got the solution for adding multiple product in cart using below lines of code by parameter in productRepository function

Comment: Easy to use this extension [Magento 2 Add Multiple Products to Cart](https://www.magespark.com/magento-2-add-multiple-products-to-cart-extension.html), which will save your time and money

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got solution for adding multiple products in cart in for loop:
Please refer below code to implement this functionality in MAGENTO 2

```
   if ($product_id) {
                    $storeId = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getId();
                    try {


                        if(isset($params['super_attribute'][$product_id])){
                            $params_post = array();
                            $params_post['form_key'] = $this->formKey->getFormKey();
                            $params_post['qty'] = 1;
                            $params_post['super_attribute'] =  $params['super_attribute'][$product_id];
                            $finalproduct = $this->productRepository->getById($product_id, false, $storeId);
                            $this->cart->addProduct($finalproduct, $params_post);
                        } else {
                            $params_post = array();
                            $params_post['form_key'] = $this->formKey->getFormKey();
                            $params_post['qty'] = 1;

                            $finalproduct = $this->productRepository->getById($product_id, false, $storeId);
                            $this->cart->addProduct($finalproduct, $params_post);
                        }

                    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {

                    }
                }
```

Comment: This will add configurable, simple and options product. You can modify this as per requirement.